# FileID received but Couldn't download Image from Google drive using Google Picker Api in Javascript

Tags: image, api, drive, google-api-js-client, google-picker

hope you all are doing well.
I am stuck on this issue for last 3 days and lot of research went wasted.
I implemented google Picker Api in my web application to let the user choose file from google drive. I got File ID successfully but unable to download file from Google drive that was my primary task.
Please have a look on the code i wrote for this purpose.
When i received file ID. I wrote these lines to get Image.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'+fileId+'?alt=media');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
  

  xhr.responseType = 'blob';

  xhr.onload = function () {

    // Better trigger and event and manage the response outside the onload function. 
    // Just for demo purposes:

    $('#THE_IMG_ID').attr( 'src', URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response) );
  };

  xhr.onerror = function () {
  };

  xhr.send();
```

but nothing is shown in the  tag with id 'THE_IMG_ID'. Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: I think that in your script when `fileId` is the file of the image file, the retrieved file is shown in `img` tag. So, can I ask you about the mimeType of the file of your file ID?

Comment: Have you inspected the contents of xhr.response? Try logging it to see if it is in the format you expect. The way you've coded, if the request is unsuccessful, `#THE_IMG_ID` src attribute will not be populated nor it'll give any warnings (logging to console for example).